# Javascript variable statement as key value pair

Tags: javascript, relay

I´m programing in javascript using Relay and I´ve found the following statement:

```
const { connectionType: UsersConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: UserType });
```

What does exactly the `{ connectionType: CustomerConnectionType }` means ? How to reference that variable later and how to export it if I have two more of those varibles, like:

```
const { connectionType: CustomerConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: CustomerType });
const { connectionType: ItemConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions( { nodeType: ItemType });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found it - it's a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). There's also other forms of it with arrays, etc. It's an ECMAScript 6 thing.

> A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

Frankly I think the syntax is confusing - I would have used `var { foo: p, bar: q}` instead (or a completely different syntax entirely, so it doesn't look confusingly similar to an object initialization), but I suppose they had their reasons.

In your case the line

```
const { connectionType: UsersConnectionType } = connectionDefinitions({nodeType:UserType});
```

is actually the equivalent of

```
const UsersConnectionType = connectionDefinitions({nodeType:UserType}).connectionType;
```

just with more bling and confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

it is a way to initialise UsersConnectionType take a look at the example

```js
function A(){
    return {x : 5};
}

let {x : y} = A();

console.log(y);
```

incase you know what the return value of the function is, you can initialise them this way .

```
{x : y}
```

here y gets assigned the value of x returned from the function A()

Comment: Confused answer. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I know my function would return an object which has a property x, I want to initialise y to the value of that property, so I can declare y like this to store whatever value was stored in the property x of the returned object

Comment: it is equivalent to let y = A().x;

Comment: You should not be able to assign value to connectionType as its a constant.
And when you cant reassign, there is no question of referring one or the other. If you use var, then second one will overwrite first one

Comment: @Vatsal how can I use the created connection type in multiple files, as every time I call it will r eference the same one ?

Comment: I am not sure how Relay works, but ideally you should have a common place, like service or some factory method which should return the connection type whenever you call it